# how to set a parameter as a global scope in a stack of nested function calls in coffescript?

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, nested, closures

```
func1 = (a) ->
           (b) =>
               (c) ->
                   (d) =>
```

Say I have code like above (perhaps more nested calls and a mix of thin and fat arrows) I want to be able to set something at func1 level so that all the functions below can see it without actually passing it as a parameter and not be able to worry about thin or the fat arrow. is that possible coffescript? it's like setting something global at the func1 level (not above it). similar to threadlocal in Java.

```
 func1 = (a) ->
             #set something here like say x = 10
             (b) =>
                 (c) ->
                     (d) => print x # should print 10
```

Comment: func1()()()() should do it!

Answer (score 0):

`func1()()()()` should do it because you are return a function object at each level therefore 4 ()'s.